# Load existing components dynamically Angular 2 Final Release

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to load dynamically a component in the final release 2.0.0.

Using RC5 I was loading using the following code:

Create a directive to load the controls:

```
import {
  CheckboxComponent, CheckboxListComponent,DatePickerComponent
} from '../components/';

@Directive({
      selector: '[ctrl-factory]'
    })
    export class ControlFactoryDirective implements OnChanges {
      @Input() model: any;

      constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentResolver) {
      }

      create(cp) {
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(cp)
          .then(factory => {
            const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
            this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
            let ch = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []).instance;
            ch.model = this.model;
        });
      }

      ngOnChanges() {
        if (!this.model) return;

        switch (this.model.type) {
          case 'checkbox':
            this.create(CheckboxComponent);
            break;
          case 'checkboxlist':
            this.create(CheckboxListComponent);
            break;
          case 'datepicker':
            this.create(DatePickerComponent);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Then loaded that directive in my page like this:

```
<div ctrl-factory *ngFor="let child of page.childrens" [model]="child"></div>
```

But after updating from rc5 to 2.0.0 final release, the resolver doesn't exist anymore, was replaced by compiler.

I found loads of places showing how to load it using different codes, but all those too complex and I couldn't make it work.

Take this for instance: [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

It looks more specific to that scenario, my one I just need to load the component and set an @Input called model.

One thing when I was trying I had to create dynamically a module for each component, then add the component to it. But then I had issues saying that the component was being set in more than one Module, try to remove in some place an not working.

The major part of the code shown, I get from this link: http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2-rc-5/

And did a couple of changes.

> Update

I manage to make it work, using the following approach:

The create method has been changed to

```
private create(cp) {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule, ControlsModule],
      declarations: []
    })
    class DynamicModule {}

    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicModule)
      .then(({componentFactories}) => {
        const compFactory = componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === cp);
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0, injector, []);
        cmpRef.instance.model = this.model;
      });
  }
```

Most places I've found, set create the Component and set it to the DynamicModule, the issue with that is when you are already declaring that same component in a different module, angular is going to complain about. The solution in my case was to import the my ControlsModule that has all my controls being exported.

Comment: I'm trying to create a similar thing. I have a JSON file that loads classes and their list of lectures. The classes are added to the nav bar and the lectures are added as a list in a detail view. On clicking a lecture, a component should be loaded in the detail view. For each lecture, there is a different component and I was thinking of creating a module or a router link for each lecture (and a router-outlet), instead of just loading a component like your example. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to load things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

**NgComponentOutlet** was introduced in **4.0.0-beta.3** https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/8578682

> Coming soon [NgComponentOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11235)

I see two options to do that:

1) Using **ComponentFactoryResolver**.

It uses the already generated factory and the code looks something like this:

```
constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
create(comp) {
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp);
  const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);

  (<any>compRef).instance.model = this.model;
}
```

In this case we have to define dynamic component in `declarations` and `entryComponents` properties within decorator of module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DynamicComponent ],
  entryComponents: [DynamicComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- [Dynamically Creating Components With Angular 2.0](http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/)
- [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7WNWQSQqcLqQr3bCyT8?p=preview)

2) Using **Compiler**

In this case we can only run module compilation by using `compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` and  then find component from componentFactories array. Your directive might look like this:

```
constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private loader: DynamicLoaderService) { }

create(comp) {
  this.loader.createComponentFactory(comp).then(factory => {
     const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);

    (<any>compRef).instance.model = this.model;
  })
}
```

`DynamicLoaderService` is a global service that will load and store component factories.

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicLoaderService {
  constructor(protected compiler: Compiler) {}

  private resolveCompHelper$ = new Subject<any>();
  private cache = new Map<string, ComponentFactory<any> | number>();

  public createComponentFactory(type: string) : Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    let factory = this.cache.get(type);

    // if factory has been already loading
    if(factory === 1) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // waiting compilation of factory
        const subscriber = this.resolveCompHelper$.subscribe((data) => {
          if(type !== data.type) return;
          subscriber.unsubscribe();
          resolve(data.factory);
        });   
      });
    } 
    // factory exists in cache
    if (factory) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(factory));
    }

    const comp = typeMap[type];
    // factory startes loading
    this.cache.set(type, 1);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(createComponentModule(comp))
        .then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) =>  {
            factory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories
              .find(x => x.componentType === comp);
            this.cache.set(type, factory);
            this.resolveCompHelper$.next({ type, factory});

            resolve(factory);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfxohn1y9bZRZoGAweWz?p=preview)**

Hope it helps you!

Comment: thanks for the amazing explanation, the link you provide from rango.io is exacly what i need to do, because my component is a modal that will render some controls inside. All thanks for the plunker examples. You helped me a lot. Is there any advantages using ComponentFactoryResolver over Compiler? I find using the first easier.

Comment: Hey Yurzui any advantage one over the other? I saw thr second one has the caching, I kinda dont need it. I was trying to figure out a way to destroy the components not only when I recreate them but once I close the dynamic modal.

Comment: Very great example.. @Yurzui - I am running into limitations that I can't nest one component into another for e.g. created another component which uses Image and Button to display together and use the new component in app.ts. Do you think that is possible? and if yes, can pls provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

It was useful for me to see this option based on a Directive, but I found the one that fit my needs based on Components: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-aot-dynamic-components/

Happy coding!