# Error with importing ComponentResolver in component ( Angular 2 )

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to import "ComponentResolver"

```
import { Component, HostListener, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ComponentResolver } from '@angular/core';
```

And I have error:

> Module '"/home/maksym/untill/trunk/unTill.Modern/Code/AppRc6/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'ComponentResolver'.

My dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
```

How i cam fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since RC.6 2.0.0-rc.6 `ComponentResolver` was removed.

Per angular2 changelog

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31

Use `ComponentFactoryResolver` together with `@NgModule.entryComponents`  or `ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS` provider for dynamic component creation.

Comment: Have  you example of using entryComponents?

Comment: See the first option from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678963/load-existing-components-dynamically-angular-2-final-release/39680765#39680765

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me!