# How to render a dynamic template with components in Angular2

Tags: angular, dynamic, compilation, components

I've tried many stackoverflow options like [Load existing components dynamically Angular 2 Final Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678963/load-existing-components-dynamically-angular-2-final-release/39680765#39680765).

What i want to do is get a html page with a ajax request and render/compile this template in my custom component.

I've figured out that angular2 has two deprecated components and that i have to use **ComponentFactoryResolver**.

In my old solution i could just set a '[innerHtml]' to render the HTML.
Now i need a new solution.

Who can help me out?

**page.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactory, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: "wd-page",
    templateUrl: "/app/page/page.component.html",
    providers: []
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

    // we need the viewcontainer ref, so explicitly define that, or we'll get back
    // an element ref.
    @ViewChild('dynamicChild', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    private target: ViewContainerRef;

    private page = {
        Source: "<div><h2>Hello world</h2><one-of-my-components></one-of-my-components></div>"
    }


    constructor(
        private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }


        ngOnInit() {
            //What code do i need here?
        }
}
```

```html
<div #dynamicChild></div>

<!-- Old implementation!

    <div *ngIf="!showSource" [innerHTML]="page">
    </div>
-->
```

Comment: `[innerHTML]` never created components. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290 might do what you want. What do you think [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactoryResolver-class.html) is deprecated?

Comment: Hi Gunter, i've tried this solution but it only works for real angular components and not custom ones. I've edited the plunkr from you're post to recreate my problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/UACDPBRWNmvjVVsr0dWC

Comment: It works with custom components https://plnkr.co/edit/TAbupH4si62x10QZ7xuc?p=preview

Comment: I can't see in a blink of an eye what you did diffently compared to my snippet. Is it because you're component is inside a second module?

Comment: Aaah now i see what i did wrong. I did not import my 'custom components' into the dynamic module. Thanks for helping me out Yurzui!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem **solved** Thanks to Yurzui,

https://plnkr.co/edit/TAbupH4si62x10QZ7xuc?p=preview

The generic HTML outlete from a different post ([Angular 2.1.0 create child component on the fly, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290)) can be used to render templates with custom directives in them.

Don't forget to import a **module** with all the custom components that you want to render!

```js
export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

// Import the module with required components here
@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, SharedModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
class DynamicHtmlModule { }

return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
   .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
    return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made **tiny changes for using my own components** (such as HomeComponent) at @Yurzui and @Linksonder 's solutions.
https://plnkr.co/edit/27x0eg?p=preview

It's basically adding AppModule to DynamicHtmlModule as additional import inside of createComponentFactory().

```
@NgModule({ imports: [AppModule, CommonModule, RouterModule, SharedModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
class DynamicHtmlModule { }
```

And exports our own components at AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  exports: [HomeComponent, AboutComponent],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```