# How to provide @Input when rendering dynamic template in Angular 2

Tags: angular, templates, input, dynamic

I am attempting to load a template dynamically at runtime, render it and bind to dynamic data from within the template.

Following the stackoverflow question [How to render a dynamic template with components in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092639/how-to-render-a-dynamic-template-with-components-in-angular2) and @Linksonder's answer I have the loading and rendering part up and running.

Now I am stuck at adding an `@Input` data to the dynamic component and to provide data so that I can bind to it from the template such as `{{ data }}`.

I extended the `ngOnChanges()` in this way so that it adds an injector with a test `inputProvider`:

```ts
createComponentFactory(this.compiler, compMetadata)
  .then(factory => {
    let inputProviders = [{provide: 'data', useValue: '1234'}];  
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.vcRef.parentInjector);

    this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
  });
```

However, trying to access the injector in DynamicComponent this way throws an error (I assume the Injector can not be resolved):

```ts
...
import { Injector} from '@angular/core';

export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {

  const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {
    data: any;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
      this.data = this.injector.get('data');
    }
  };

  const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

  @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
  class DynamicHtmlModule { }

  return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
   .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
    return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Also if you have other approaches that solve the problem please let me know.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you can try: `@Component(metadata) class DynamicComponent {...}` instead of trying to save the classes in `const`s?
Same way you'd normally define a component basically

Comment: Did it help anyhow?

Comment: You can directly set property of component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this should work for you:

```
@Injectable()
class DynamicComponent {
  data: any;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.data = this.injector.get('data');
  }
}

export function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(DynamicComponent);

    @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, SharedModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }

    compiler.clearCacheFor(decoratedCmp);
    return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
       .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
        return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
      });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IUd0zfx3EX1vm2PMcR1O?p=preview)**

Comment: As suggested, the `@Injectable` decorator was missing. Works nicely now!