# Dynamic add component using gridstack and angular2? Jquery $.parseHTML does not work

Tags: angular, gridstack

I have the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmLk2ey7/7/)

I want to be able to stick my custom component into a specific grid (e.g. "")

Right now without Angular2, I just use:

```
var el = $.parseHTML("<div><div class=\"grid-stack-item-content\" data-id=\""+id+"\"/><div/>");
this.grid.add_widget(el, 0, 0, 6, 5, true);
```

The issue is, I have no idea how I could do something like:

```
var el = $.parseAndCompileHTMLWithComponent("<div><div class=\"grid-stack-item-content\" data-id=\""+id+"\"/><fancy-button></fancy-button><div/>");
this.grid.add_widget(el, 0, 0, 6, 5, true);
```

In angular1, I know there is a compile, but in angular2, there is no such thing.

My fancy-button component is straightforward and is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fancy-button',
  template: `<button>clickme</button>`
})
export class FancyButton {}
```

How can I dynamically add the fancy-button component?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: I am not sure I understand what are you trying to do. at the moment gridstack support angular 1 only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easist way to add `fancy-button` component dynamically might be as follows:

**1)** Add component to `entryComponents` array of your module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, GridStackComponent, FancyButtonComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ FancyButtonComponent ], // <== here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**2)** Get root node from compiled component

```
constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

getRootNodeFromParsedComponent(component) {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
  const ref = this.vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory, this.vcRef.length, this.vcRef.injector);
  const hostView = <EmbeddedViewRef<any>>ref.hostView;
  return hostView.rootNodes[0];
}
```

**3)** Use it anywhere

```
const fancyBoxElement = this.getRootNodeFromParsedComponent(FancyBoxComponent);  
$('#someId').append(fancyBoxElement);
```

Here's **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qt4S6GJJCHdveZVcmCOS?p=preview)** for your case

If you're looking for something more complicated then there are a lot of answers where you can use angular compiler to do it working

- [Load existing components dynamically Angular 2 Final Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678963/load-existing-components-dynamically-angular-2-final-release)
- [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)
- [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)
- [Angular 2.1.0 create child component on the fly, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically)
- [How to manually lazy load a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module)

Comment: @yuzui I tried this example, I get **this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory is not a function** error

Comment: @rish can you provide some plunker?

Comment: @yuzui thnx for reply, https://plnkr.co/edit/EPYcF3qFEkYhc12WVEeD?p=preview

Comment: @rish If you want create component with dynamic html then you have to use `Compiler`. I updated your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/GDyJk0GGPOF5opax5cwX?p=preview As you can see i get `HtmlElement` and add it to `document.body`

Comment: @yuzui thnx it's really helped me, just one question here, can we create these two methods inside normal class which has no [at]Component and [at]Directives?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Angular 2’s ViewContainerRef class, which provides a handy createComponent method. The ViewContainerRef can be informally thought of as a location in the DOM where new components can be inserted.

```
this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
```

[Here's a working plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvILwmOLvrS2PxIrXX8?p=preview).

Or you can use the generic HTML outlete from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290)

Comment: There are a lot of DynamicComoponentLoader threads, but those answers are not relevant, because it has been deprecated.