# Access the programatically created child components in parent template - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am adding/removing dynamically created child components from parent component. This is my child component:

```
<div class="form-container">
<div class="form-item">
    <label class="edit-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="edit-input" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" [formControl]="name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
    <label class="edit-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="edit-input" name="email" placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com" [formControl]="email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
    <label class="edit-label" for="contact">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="edit-input" name="contact" placeholder="03xx-xxxxxxx" [formControl]="contact" required>
</div>
<div class="form-item" *ngIf = "showRemove != false">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger"
    (click)="removeObject()" > Remove</button>
</div>
```

It's being used in the parent component like this:

```
<div #newUserParent></div>
```

This is the parent ts file:

```
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {

 selectedMode = "existing";
 @ViewChild('newUserParent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container:     ViewContainerRef; 

  users: IMultiSelectOption[];
  usersModel: number[];
  usersSettings: IMultiSelectSettings = {
  enableSearch: true
  }

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, 
          private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  addComponent(showRemove = true) {
   console.log('adding component');
   //check and resolve the component
   var comp = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(NewUserComponent);
   //create component inside container
   var newUserComponent = this.container.createComponent(comp);
   newUserComponent.instance._ref = newUserComponent;
   newUserComponent.instance.showRemove = showRemove;
 }

 addUser() {
   console.log('add user');
   //dynamically go through the components and get the 
 }

 isValid() {
   var isValid = true;
   console.log(this.container.length); //returns the no. of components added
   //traverse through the components and see if they are valid or not
   for(let index = 0; index<this.container.length; index++) {

    // I want to basically go through the components and call their public functions and also access their public properties
    let component = this.container.get(index); console.log(component);
    let instance = component['_view']['nodes'][1];
    console.log(instance);
    // isValid = component.instance.isValid();
   }
   return isValid;
 }

}
```

**Problem Statement**
The problem that I am facing here is that I know how to add components and how each component has a Component Factory associated with it and how its view gets created in the ViewContainerReference. What I fail to understand is how we can traverse through ViewContainerReference and get back the components and call their functions. I am able to access the properties through the code I have written above, but it seems wrong. There must be a better approach. I have also gone through the class of ViewContainerReference and couldn't understand which function can help me out here

Comment: @hrdkisback I don't understand how this link is similar to my problem. In my case I have dynamically created components in my parent template and I need a way to traverse those and see if the user has added right data, etc

Comment: @alina, try `this.container.get(index).context` to get access to component instance or just store somewhere`this.container.createComponent(comp).instance`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com thankyou your second approach worked for me :)

Comment: @alina sorry actually that was wrong link i wanted to give you this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678963/load-existing-components-dynamically-angular-2-final-release

Comment: @hrdkisback that's okay. I was able to solve my problem, however, I'll still look into this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using @AngularInDepth's approach. The first one didn't work for me since I couldn't find context, but the second one did. I was trying to do the same thing, but instead of adding the 'instance' of the component in an array, I was pushing the entire (this.container.createComponent(comp)) in an array which was causing problems for me.